# Problem with VideoCapture in OpenCV 2.3

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, video, opencv, video-processing

I have problem in using **VideoCapture** calss for opening a MPEG video file. The code was compile properly. However, during the running time, it can not open the file and give me the following warning message:

**warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:477)**

I have  this problem only when I build my code in debug mode. I relsease mode the code works correctly.

The code also works correctly in the *c* style using **CvCapture** and **cvCaptureFromAVI** (in both release and debug mode), however, I'd like to develop my code in more C++ style.

(I am using OpenCV 2.3 in Visual-studio (C++) 10)

Thank you for you helps

Comment: Having the same issue here. Didn't solved it yet.

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue. If I run my code in Visual Studio, it works fine. If I run outside of Visual Studio, it can't find the video.

Answer (score 1):

Check your include paths. It sounds like the build environment is properly configured for Release-mode but not Debug-mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem with opencv 2.4.2   In my case I changed it to opencv 2.4.3. Now it is working. But some works like face detection are not working with opencv 2.4.3.  Build a new project and include the directories of opencv 2.4.3 . It will work then.

Comment: Since you're obviously uncertain about whether this might help, it should be a comment, not an answer.